# Figure Positioning Chaos

Tags: floats

I have a document with seven figures following each other, and I want to place some text after the last one, the problem is that no matter how I try, the text goes up to be after the first figure and not the last.

What do I have to tune to make sure my text will stay in place?

code:

```
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/uno.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/dos.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/tres.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/cuatro.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/cinco.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/seis.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/siete.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

Para la realización de este último ejercicio se han ido siguiendo las instrucciones facilitadas en el enunciado. Como detalle a mencionar, la envolvente no se ajusta perfectamente a la portadora y banda lateral (PBL) como puede apreciarse en la siguiente figura.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/anadido.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

You can notice there is another figure after the text called anadido, that is okay that has to go there too.

Any good tutorial on how to get around latex figures will be much apreciated too.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `p` in `\begin{figure}[p]` means that the figure will go in a page without any text, so all of them queue up until the page of text is shipped out. Change the`p` to `htp` and it will work.

Comment: or perhaps simpler just put `\clearpage` before the `Para la realizac...` text so no figures float past that point.

Comment: Try placing a `\clearpage` before your closing paragraph.

Comment: A good tutorial? See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: It is worth noting that you can use `\includegraphics` directly and it is positioned the same way as text, the _only_ reason to use the `figure` enviornment is to allow the content to be moved automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  I hope your problem is solved.  But please remember to include a minimal working example with your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If andido is okay, you can try to use the same code as anadido. if you want to separate each figure in one page, use the `\newpage`

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/uno.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/dos.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/tres.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/cuatro.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/cinco.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/seis.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/siete.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

Para la realización de este último ejercicio se han ido siguiendo las instrucciones facilitadas en el enunciado. Como detalle a mencionar, la envolvente no se ajusta perfectamente a la portadora y banda lateral (PBL) como puede apreciarse en la siguiente figura.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Trabajo_en_curso/Figuras/ILS/anadido.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```